# Simple advertise block drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, ads

I'm looking for a simple module/code that allow me to manage advertisement.

I've tried many modules but I found just complex stuff and with non logical structure, I've also tried to edit some modules but the are too much work to do.

I'd like just to create custom block with an image field and a tracking system (impressions, click etc).
So the ad manager can just go to the page, click on the context link, see the impressions/click and he can upload new pic for the ad.

I mean something really easy and intuitive, I place the blocks around the site, the ad manager (website admin) upload manage blocks.

I cant find anything that works in this simple way, and I cant figure out how to write down some code for get this easy system work.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the module Simpleads. I'm using it on a site right for doing simple ad tracking like you described.

Here is a link to the module.  http://drupal.org/project/simpleads

Comment: yap, that's the module that i'm actually using.. but i have to create and ad campaig witch create the block, then i have to put the block in the tpl and i cant just click on the block and uplaod images and see the impressions/click

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using this module http://drupal.org/project/ad , i guess this will help you

Comment: it's just for d6, cant use a dev stuff on the site that i'm developing

Comment: check this out http://blog.urbaninsight.com/2012/02/17/simpleads-new-advertisement-module-for-drupal-7